# Is there some way to define a variable as a function such that calling the variable at some given time will return the function's output at that time?

Tags: c++, variables, c++17

Essentially, I'm trying to do something like

```
#define foobar foo.bar()
```

But without the use of #define, so I can write something along the lines of

```
double foobar = foo.bar();
```

Obviously, compiling the code above will just define foobar as whatever foo.bar() returns at the time of definition. What I want to do is the above in such a way that using foobar at some time in the code will just use whatever foo.bar() returns at that time, and not whatever it was at definition of foobar.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a `class`, and add the desired behavior to that class, so instance *variables* of that class will return the member function's output.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `#define`?

Comment: So, basically, the goal is to be able to write `x` instead of `x()`?

Comment: Do you just want to delay the call to `foo.bar()` until `foobar` is *first* accessed? Or do you want `foobar` to return a different value *every* time it's read?

Comment: That syntax would be rather surprising to the user, IMO. It would be better to use `foobar()` instead to behave like `foo.bar()`. That can also be achieved in C++ without macros.

Comment: `"will just define foobar as whatever foo.bar() returns at the time of definition"` I think you're wrong here. The preprocessor copies `foo.bar()` to whereever it finds `foobar`. There is no evalutation at "definition time"

Comment: Getting some kind of behavior like this would be possible with an `operator double()` as a class member. But the idea really breaks down as soon as you try `auto& x=  foobar;`

Comment: I would suggest not doing this.  It makes the code more difficult to understand.  What will look like a variable in your code is actually a function which goes against the principle of least surprise.

Comment: You really, really, really do *not* want this, either with or without a macro. You're only going to end up cursing yourself for causing yourself so much trouble.

Comment: If you give some more information on what the `bar` function does, there might be alternative solutions. For example, if it is a simple getter function that returns some member of `foo`, you can make it return a reference and that will always be the "current" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, compiling the code above will just define foobar as whatever foo.bar() returns at the time of definition. What I want to do is the above in such a way that using foobar at some time in the code will just use whatever foo.bar() returns at that time, and not whatever it was at definition of foobar.

You want a function not a variable:

```
auto foobar() { return foo.bar(); }
```

If `foo` is not a global (i hope so) and you want to declare the callable on the fly just as you can declare a `double`, you can use a lambda expression:

```
Foo foo;
auto foobar = [&foo](){ return foo.bar(); };

// call it:
foobar();
```

To call the function without the function call syntax `()` you could use a custom type that calls the function when converted to the returned type. However, as this is non-idiomatic obfuscation, I am not going into more details.